# Comma between "well then"?

Tags: commas

Which is correct?

> Well, then ... come on in!
>
> Well then ... come on in!

I have tried searching the phrase "well(,) then" on Google, but both variants come up equally often, it seems. But I'm not sure the examples with comma all correspond to the meaning I'm after, which is "well then = if that is the case, okay" or "well then = ".

Comment: I'd say the (internal) commaless version is more common by quite a way. Certainly, a terminal comma (or perhaps dash or ellipse) is required.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct and convey essentially the same meaning you've already concluded.  Personally I wouldn't combine the comma and the ellipsis that way, but that could just be a matter of style.

The only noteworthy difference I see between them is that the first one, being spoken, involves two pauses:  "Well (short pause) then (longer pause) come on in!" whereas the second leaves out that first short pause.  This could imply that a person saying the first is a little more hesitant in his/her decision to welcome the person in.

Answer (score 1):

> Well,

is an interjection *used to acknowledge a statement or situation*  [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well#Interjection)

For example [example my own]:

> A: Could you wait outside for a bit?
>
> B: But I have class in two minutes.
>
> A: Well (then), come on in.

You don't actually need to use *then*.

Comment: . . . and if you do use *well* ***then***, the comma goes after both words—as you indicated in the last example.

Comment: Why is the two-comma version not available?